# Compare first row to other rows

Tags: oracle

The issue I face that I need after selecting multiple rows,to loop over each row and fetch those who have some related information to the first row.

Example:

```
select NAME,ENGLISH_GRADE,FRANCE_GRAE
from (some complex query that have order by and returns 100 rows) WHOLE_ROWS
where

//Here I need to loop over WHOLE_ROWS and make something like that:
//if(currentRow.ENGLISH_GRADE==WHOLE_ROWS(0).ENGLISH_GRADE)
//fetch this row
```

Comment: I believe you will have to use a anonymous PL-SQL block for this. Have you looked into the docs ?

Comment: Frankly I just need it as a pure SQL without any PL-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to join your query to itself. You can do with with a subquery factoring clause:

```
WITH complex_query AS
    ( ... complex query here ... ) 
SELECT 
  FROM complex_query cq1
 WHERE cq1.english_grade = ( SELECT english_grade FROM cq1
                              WHERE rownum = 1 )
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a007/1). You could also do this with analytics, but those seem to me more difficult to understand.